# Python- plotting not available

Tags: python, python-2.7, plot, network-programming, igraph

I have tried running the code found at http://computationallegalstudies.com/2009/11/15/programming-dynamic-models-in-python-3-outbreak-on-a-network/ but at the end the following shows up:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 446, in plot
    result = Plot(target, bbox, background=kwds.get("background", "white"))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 117, in __init__
    self._surface_was_created = not isinstance(target, cairo.Surface)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/utils.py", line 396, in __getattr__
    raise TypeError("plotting not available")
TypeError: plotting not available
```

It's a code for modelling SIR model on networks. I really need someone's help as I am not able to use a computer , a mac in this case. Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there a tag for igraph/drawing or whatever the name of the lib you're using is? This is not a general Python question as this is not a built-in lib (AFAIK), but that's how it's tagged right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Cairo library and its Python bindings for plotting. If you are using Homebrew, it is simply a matter of `brew install cairo py2cairo`, assuming that you use the system Python (which you seem to be, judging from the stack trace).

Comment: Cairo and py2cairo are already installed.  I better precise that I am running a code for an SRI model on networks and  that what it is not plotting is the network.What am I suppose to do?

Comment: Try typing `import cairo` at the Python prompt. If it doesn't work, it means that `py2cairo` is not installed properly. If it works, then the plotting in igraph should also work (since igraph simply tries `import cairo` first and then replaces Cairo with a fake module that just raises an exception printing `plotting not available` if `import cairo` failed).

Comment: I typed import cairo and this came up:                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 1>", line 1, in <module>
    import cairo
ImportError: No module named cairo.    What can I do now ? Thank you in advance. How do I install it properly?

Comment: As I wrote above, `brew install cairo py2cairo` should be enough if you are using Homebrew. If you don't, then unfortunately you are on your own - you have to compile it from source somehow.